# PostgreSQL: update with left outer self join ignored 

Tags: sql, postgresql, join, sql-update

I want to update the column `leaf_category` with `TRUE` where the category is not a parent category. It works as a select statement:

```
 select 
     c1.id, c1.name, c1.slug, c1.level, c2.parent_id, c2.name, c2.slug, c2.level 
 from
     catalog_category c1 
 left outer join 
     catalog_category c2 on 
     (c1.id = c2.parent_id)
 where 
     c2.parent_id is null;
```

However, the corresponding `UPDATE` sets all the columns to `TRUE`.

```
update catalog_category 
set leaf_category = True
from
    catalog_category c1 
left outer join 
    catalog_category c2 on 
    (c1.id = c2.parent_id)
 where 
     c2.parent_id is null;
```

Is an `UPDATE` like that possible at all?

Answer (score 11):

You are just missing a connecting `WHERE` clause:

```
UPDATE catalog_category c
SET    leaf_category = true
FROM   catalog_category c1 
LEFT   JOIN catalog_category c2 ON c1.id = c2.parent_id
WHERE  c.id = c1.id
AND    c2.parent_id IS NULL;
```

This form with `NOT EXISTS` is probably faster, doing the same:

```
UPDATE catalog_category c
SET    leaf_category = true
WHERE  NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT FROM catalog_category c1
    WHERE  c1.parent_id = c.id
    );
```

[The manual for `UPDATE`.](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-update.html)

Related:

- [Select rows which are not present in other table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19363481/select-rows-which-are-not-present-in-other-table/19364694#19364694)

Comment: @Dems: You can use an alias for the table to be updated, but the `c1` relation is in the `FROM` clause. In PostgreSQL, unlike MySQL, only *one* table can be updated at a time. This corresponds to the SQL standard if I am not mistaken - while the additional `FROM` clause is a PostgreSQL extension of the standard.

Comment: Thanks Erwin. It worked and it is shorter. By experimenting I found by swapping parent_id and id in the subclause it returns the root categories.

Comment: The first statement will not work as PostgreSQL does not support the `JOIN` keyword in FROM clause for the `UPDATE` statement. You have to use "implicit joins" in the WHERE clause

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: You are mistaken, the statement is tested and works. We've had the same thing a couple of days ago [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10377302/postgresql-database-inner-join-query-error/10377333#comment13385825_10377333).

Comment: Interesting. It is certainly not clearly visible in the manual. But as it links to the standard FROM clause I guess that's where it comes from. You live and learn ;)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: I see now that I forgot to `@`-notify you in the other comment. Sorry about that.