# PostgreSQL Database - Inner Join Query Error

Tags: php, sql, postgresql

With the help of this community, I was able to produce a query using an inner join which I thought would work for what I'm trying to do. Unfortunately, when I attempted to run the query found below, I received the following error:

ERROR:  table name "bue" specified more than once

---

From what I've read on Google, some people have said that the "FROM bue" is not needed, but when I removed this, I got another error found below:

ERROR:  syntax error at or near "INNER" at character 98

---

I'd very much appreciate your assistance in troubleshooting this. Thank you so very much.

---

Query:

```
UPDATE
  bue
SET
  rgn_no = chapterassociation.rgn_no,
  chp_cd = chapterassociation.chp_cd
FROM
  bue
INNER JOIN
  chapterassociation
    ON  bue.work_state = chapterassociation.work_state
    AND bue.bgu_cd = chapterassociation.bgu_cd
WHERE
  bue.mbr_no IS NULL AND bue.chp_cd IS NULL
```

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?  You seem to start out with UPDATE, but then jump to things used when you are trying to return  data from a query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In PostgreSQL, specifying the table to be updated needs to be done only in the UPDATE clause, e.g. `UPDATE bue`.  The FROM clause is only for *additional* tables referenced in the query.  (If you were doing a self-join on `bue`, you would mention it again in the FROM clause, but you aren't in this case.)

The second error you get is likely just a simple syntax error.  The other tricky thing is that JOIN/ON syntax doesn't fit in the FROM clause, so you have to move the join conditions to the WHERE clause.  Try something like:

```
UPDATE
  bue
SET
  rgn_no = chapterassociation.rgn_no,
  chp_cd = chapterassociation.chp_cd
FROM
  chapterassociation
WHERE
  bue.mbr_no IS NULL AND bue.chp_cd IS NULL
  AND bue.work_state = chapterassociation.work_state
  AND bue.bgu_cd = chapterassociation.bgu_cd
```

See http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-update.html.

(N.B. At least I don't know how to put JOIN/ON into an UPDATE statement... I could be missing something.)

Comment: You are not missing anything. You cannot use `JOIN` or `INNER JOIN` in an UPDATE statement.

Comment: To be precise: you can't use `JOIN` to link the (one!) table in the `UPDATE` clause to (one or more) table(s) in the `FROM` clause. You *can* `JOIN` tables *in* the `FROM` clause normally, though.