# Have SQL query fail if subquery returns null

Tags: sql, postgresql, subquery

If the below subquery finds no records it returns null and sets the action_batch_id as so. Is it possible to have the entire query fail/exit if the subquery returns no records?

```
UPDATE action_batch_items 
SET action_batch_id = (SELECT id FROM action_batches WHERE id = '123' 
AND batch_count < 1000  AND batch_size < 100000) 
WHERE id = 1234567
```

UPDATE: Here's the structure (it's ActiveRecord)

```
CREATE TABLE "public"."action_batches" (
    "id" int8 NOT NULL,
    "action_batch_container_id" int8 NOT NULL,
    "action_message" json,
    "adaptor" json,
    "batch_count" int4 DEFAULT 0,
    "batch_size" int8 DEFAULT 0
)

CREATE TABLE "public"."action_batch_items" (
    "id" int8 NOT NULL,
    "action_batch_id" int8,
    "config" json
)
```

Comment: This might help: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8766815/1073631 -- assuming you have a field to `join` on... Does `action_batch_items` have an `action_batches_id`?

Comment: as i didn't get you wrong, but this query is really really weird to me. you update action_batch_id to the result of the subquery, but in your subquery, let's check it out. you select ID and where id = '123'. so no all of the result should be 123 or null? as you asked you expected 123 or no change at all?

Comment: @sgeddes it's ActiveRecord doing raw SQL but yes an action_batch_item has an action_batch_id

Comment: Your inner subquery is confusing.  If you have `WHERE id = '123'` doesn't this mean that the `id` assigned to `action_batch_id` will always be `123` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
create or replace function raise_error(text) returns int as $$
begin
  raise exception '%', $1;
  return -1;
end; $$ language plpgsql;
```

and then

```
action_batch_id = coalesce((select id ...), raise_error('No data'));
```

Comment: Can the `COALESCE()` function accept multiple records/values as input?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Surely not. However `update .. set = (select ...)` does not accept multi-row result too.

Comment: Doesn't your solution mean that an error would potentially be raised for _every_ record in the `action_batch_items` table?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Nope. Only for the first failed.

Comment: @Abelisto I already put coalesce in every part of my select, but I did not think about it, thank you, my friend!

Comment: @FábioZangirolami IMO something like `raise(text)` and `raiseif(condition, text)` should be included to the SQL standard :) Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Try using `COALESCE()`:

```
UPDATE action_batch_items 
SET action_batch_id = 
(
    SELECT COALESCE(id, action_batch_id)
    FROM action_batches
    WHERE id = '123' AND batch_count < 1000  AND batch_size < 100000
) 
WHERE id = 1234567
```

In the event that the subquery returns `NULL` the `action_batch_id` column will not be changed.  In the case of the subquery returning one or more non `NULL` records, your `UPDATE` will behave as before.

Comment: dude,but action_batch_id is in table action_batch_items, he didn't mention that action_batches also have action_batch_id, and if so. it will might be different from the batch_id from item table

Comment: Good point.  I will wait for his comment regarding this then.  The columns of the outer query should be visible in the subquery.

Comment: `action_batch_id` will be changed for empty subquery result (0 rows). `coalesce` should to wrap subquery, not vice versa.

Comment: Is there anything inherently evil in setting the `action_batch_id` to the same value?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen added the structure

Comment: I could be attacking this wrong but the goal is to not assign a batch item to a batch that is full (over batch_count or batch_size)

Comment: The logic in your query is confusing to me.